# Determining Maximal Orders of a Quaternion Algebra

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, quaternions

Let $F=\left(\frac{a,b}{K}\right)$ be a quaternion algebra for some number field $K$. What method do we use to determine a maximal order of $F$ (or the class of maximal orders of $F$)?

Comment: Ivanyos and Rónyai have published [an algorithm for handling this task](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=218891). IIRC it is implemented in at least MAGMA. I do recall that implementation running out of mem when we tried to use it on a large cyclic algebra. We managed to use the ideas and known special facts about our case to find a maximal order. I'm afraid the details have mostly faded from my mind even though I was in charge of that part of our joint paper.

Comment: The idea was to build orders mapping a suitable lattice to itself. I & R had a useful way of alternately increasing the lattice and the related order alternately, but I don't remember any of the details.